# MS Access - populate form by clicking on record in subform

Tags: microsoft-access

Have a form with all the necessary fields. About 100 fields on different tabs. On the form I have a subform (from query) that shows a portion of the fields. I want to click on a record on that subform and have it populate the form.

EXAMPLE:
query has ID, HEADLINE, DATE, OWNER, SEVERITY
This lists all the records.
Want user to scroll through this and click on a record. This will populate the form below it with all the pertinent info. The form's fields are bound to the table from which I based the form.

Not looking to add any info in, this is all for historical purposes, no new info will be entered.

Any easy way to do this?
Thanks,
b

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Asking "*Any easy way to do this?*" is not a good question because to answer depends on your experience level. So we cannot really answer that question. Please edit your question to ask something specific. Also include what have you tried so far and what were the results.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).